# Not able to retain state on-reload

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a search bar and when a package name is inputted, it renders the details of the package. The problem is on reload it goes back to the old state and doesn't show the package details anymore. I have two sibling components: `main` and `navbar` and an `input` which is the package name. I tried to use `sessionStorage` to save the state but that didn't work

```
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setInput(window.sessionStorage.getItem('input'));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('input', input);
  }, [input]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar setInput={setInput} />
      <div className="sections">
        {input ? (
          <Main input={input} />
        ) : (
          <h1
            style={{
              color: 'black',
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '46%',
              left: '50%',
              transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
            }}
          >
            Search for a NPM package
          </h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so easy to see what causes to error without seeing values of state and session storage but I guess your issue related with `JSON.parse`. Try with these modifications inside `useEffect` and initial `state` value

```
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(sessionStorage.getItem('input') ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('input') : '');

  useEffect(() => {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('input')){
        setInput(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('input'));
    } 
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('input', input);
  }, [input]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar setInput={setInput} />
      <div className="sections">
        {input ? (
          <Main input={input} />
        ) : (
          <h1
            style={{
              color: 'black',
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '46%',
              left: '50%',
              transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
            }}
          >
            Search for a NPM package
          </h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The error was not actually related to `JSON.parse` but your ans worked after removing it

Comment: The value of input is just a single string, for example: `node`